# How can a SYN flood affect a router in this scenario?

Tags: ddos, router, denial-of-service, flooding

I'm using two routers in my home network, as described [in this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/239991/218666) (router B in the diagram). Therefore, router B is **not** accessible from the internet.

Going over the logs of this router, I was surprised to find what is logged as "SYN flood". I have several entries such as:
Nov 18 21:27:50 [ATTACK]: SYN Flood from 173.194.222.188
Nov 18 12:58:16 [ATTACK]: SYN Flood from 209.85.233.188
There are 3-4 such entries per day. I haven't noticed any disruption in use. The IPs are supposed to originate from companies such as Google or Microsoft, but something tells me they are spoofed.
**Questions**

- How can a router which is not accessible from the internet be a subject of such an attack? Note that I have full control of all devices connected to it, and they are all trustworthy/up-to-date.
- Does a SYN flood attack against a home router have a meaning anyway? I was under the impression SYN flood attacks are related to servers.

I also took a look at [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72954/how-could-a-syn-flood-affect-a-home-router), and I should note I don't have any port forwarding active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect from a decive in the LAN of router B to an external service, router B and A each do network address translation (NAT) so your device can receive an answer.

So basically there is a temporary port open to receive the answers and send them back to your device.
The impact should be very limited, since normally the router accept only incoming traffic, if a device started the communication from the inside and the packages belong to that communication.

But in RFC 5382 is a possibility for port reuse: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5382#section-4.3
If such a feature is enabled, an outside service could try to establish a connection through SYN packages. Does your routers support that feature?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm unable to find such a setting on the router page. FWIW, the router firewall is on, UPnP is off, and WAN Ping respond is off.